# jQuery: replacing HTML with dynamic HTML instead of appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So far, I've got this code:

```
$("<div/>", {
    "id": "myId",
    "class": "myClass",
    "html": "Hello world!"
}).appendTo("#myContainer");
```

This appends

```
<div id="myId" class="myClass">Hello world!</div>
```

to `#myContainer`, as one would expect.

But instead of appending, I would like to have it replace the contents.
I'm imagining something like this:

```
$("#myContainer").html("<div/>", {
    "id": "myId",
    "class": "myClass",
    "html": "Hello world!"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is really easy to do, you just have to wrap the dynamic HTML in `$()` (or `jquery()`, if you prefer) again:

```
$("#myContainer").html($("<div/>", {
    "id": "myId",
    "class": "myClass",
    "html": "Hello world!"
}));
```

Even though this works perfectly fine, I'm wondering if there's a more elegant/performant way of doing this.